# initializing a list<>

Tags: c#, list, generics, initialization

When I use this line, I get an error:

```
tradesThisBar=new List<Traid>;
```

error:
*A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type*

How do I initialize it?  I initialize it in the declaration but I need to reset it.

also, will this line work?:

```
if (tradesThisBar!=null){}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error has specified, add `()` after your type:

```
tradesThisBar=new List<Traid>();
```

---

Regarding the 2nd snippet of code, the code you enter into the `{}` will only be ran if `tradesThisBar` is not `null`.

In terms of whether it will "work" depends on what you wish for it to do. But it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the constructor:

```
tradesThisBar = new List<Traid>();
```

If you want to reset it:

```
tradesThisBar = null;
```